# ng update command throwing 404 on one machine while works on other on angular upgrade

Tags: angular

We are trying to upgrade our angular application(v5) to latest and we tried to follow step listed on https://update.angular.io/. We are taking step by step version upgrade for it i.e. v5->v6-> v7....

We followed following step while upgrading from v5 to v6

1. Remove old angular cli and install angular cli v6 globally

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli@6
   ```
2. Install the angular cli v6 locally

   ```
   npm install @angular/cli@6
   ```

Looking into other online resources, at this point we supposed to get the warning message but we have not got any.

3. update angular cli

   ```
   ng update @angular/cli
   ```

Also, I tried

```
 ng update @angular/cli@6
```

Step 3 is giving different 404 error each time we run it like

- 404 Not Found: codelyzer
- 404 Not found extract-textwebpack-plugin
- ...

I checked all packages that is throwing 404 error and all those packages does exist on dev dependency part.

I created simple angular v5 project using angular cli and try to execute above steps and I am getting same 404 error. But creating same exact v5 project on other machine and running above steps converts to v6 successfully.I am not sure why it is working on one machine and noton other machine. I also ran

```
  npm cache verify
```

I have same exact node, angular cli (local and global) version installed on both machine. can someone assist me what are the steps I am missing here or any extra package I need to install to make it work?

Comment: Check if you have the two dependencies on your package.json. Try to remove them.

Comment: @Guiditox  : yup all those dependacy that is throwing 404 error exist on package.json file

Comment: Please, share your package json, showing these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation here you can see that you need to specify version 6 and not try to update to the latest version (https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=5.0-6.0)

At step 3 do this: `ng update @angular/cli@6`

Comment: I tried it but it is showing same 404 errors